# MongoDb update if exists?

Tags: php, mongodb

i am trying the logic `( insert if not exists , but if exists update the records )`

i am new to MongoDB , but i use to do that with mysql , is it possible to achieve this using mongoDB ?

here is my code so far which is working well in case `( insert if not exists )` but not in `( update if exists )`

```
$db = new MongoDB\Client($conn);
    $collection = $db->auth->users;
        
        $collection->createIndex(
            array( "username" => 1 ),
            array( "unique" => true )
        );
        
    $document = array(
        "title" => "Mraaxs",
        "fullname" => "John C12344",
        "username" => "user1",
        "age" => 22
    );
    
    $collection->updateOne(
        array("username" => $document["username"]),
        array('$setOnInsert' => $document),
        array("upsert" => true)
    );
```

Comment: What is not working about the current code? Is it resulting in an error, duplicate document, no change, something else?

Comment: @user20042973 as i mention in my question ( the code is working fine ) except the update part it is not updating data if its changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to change `$setOnInsert` to `$set`.

According to the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) for `$setOnInsert`:

> If an update operation with upsert: true results in an insert of a document, then `$setOnInsert` assigns the specified values to the fields in the document. **If the update operation does not result in an insert, `$setOnInsert` does nothing.**

So it behaves exactly as you described. `$setOnInsert` works for "insert if not exists" and does nothing for "update if exists".

`$set` will always update/put data into the document.

Here is a [good example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#example) for your case from the documentation, using both `$set` and `$setOnInsert`.

```
db.products.updateOne(
  { _id: 1 },
  {
     $set: { item: "apple" },
     $setOnInsert: { defaultQty: 100 }
  },
  { upsert: true }
)

When the upsert parameter is true db.collection.updateOne()
 - creates a new document
 - applies the $set operation
 - applies the $setOnInsert operation

The products collection contains the newly-inserted document:

{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "apple", "defaultQty" : 100 }
```

So the solution will be:

```
... 
$collection->updateOne(
    array("username" => $document["username"]),
    array('$set' => $document),
    array("upsert" => true)
);
```

Note: optionally, you can use `$setOnInsert` to store `created_at` for new documents:

```
$collection->updateOne(
    array("username" => $document["username"]),
    array('$set' => $document, '$setOnInsert' => ['created_at' => time()]),
    array("upsert" => true)
);
```

Comment: exactly what i am looking for , i have seen $set but i didn't complete my ready about it as its point to set data not update them XD i guess i should not ignore reading anymore

Comment: can relate :) every time I promise myself to "read the documentation properly next time"... :)))